# Can I install Cyanogen OS on Yu Yuphoria (with Stock Android)

Tags: cyanogenmod, operating-system, micromax-yu-yuphoria

I recently bought a YU Yuphoria shipped with Stock Android which is really freaking me as people are saying that *Yuphoria shipped with Cyanogen OS*  is far better than the *Yuphoria shipped with stock Android*. So, is there anyway I can put Cyanogen OS now on my Yuphoria??

Comment: Doesn't Yuphoria already come with Cyanogen installed? And could you be specific on what exactly is the feature you are interested in that is missing in your phone right now?

Comment: Yes but I chose the android stock rom from amazon, they've got both.

Comment: In case you aren't aware CyanogenMod is different from Cyanogen OS while the former is developed by community members Cyanogen OS is the official ROM from Cyanogen Team. Here's a link explaining how to [Manually Install CyanogenMod 12.1 on YU Yuphoria](http://www.yurekasupport.com/2015/09/manually-install-cyanogenmod-121-on-yu-yuphoria.html). Installing any custom ROM means, a preliminary requirement is you need to root your device first. Also [this Cyanogen wiki](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_lettuce) has step by step details on the same.

Comment: @Lucky What OP is trying to tell is that Yu Yuphoria comes with both version - [Cyanogen OS version](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B00XTWAAYW) and [Android Stock version](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B015W4UQJS). Related thread on [official forum](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/yuphoria-now-available-with-stock-android.24663/)

Comment: Here you go: **[\[Guide\] Flash COS12 on Yuphoria Android Version](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/guide-flash-cos12-on-yuphoria-android-version.25868/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you want cyanogen OS on your yuphoria on android then you can go to the nearest service center and get it on your phone. 
You can check it on their [website](http://www.yuplaygod.com/). I haven't done it yet, but you can give it a shot

Comment: Here you go: **[\[Guide\] Flash COS12 on Yuphoria Android Version](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/guide-flash-cos12-on-yuphoria-android-version.25868/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yu Yuphoria comes with 2 different version

- [Cyanogen OS version](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B00XTWAAYW)
- [Stock Android Version](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B015W4UQJS)

[Related thread](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/yuphoria-now-available-with-stock-android.24663/) on Official forum.

---

To get *Cyanogen OS* : You can scroll down to files to your device on Official [Cyanogen - Support](https://cyngn.com/support) page. Or Download directly [Cyanogen OS 12.1 - 5.1.1](http://builds.cyngn.com/factory/lettuce/cm-12.1-YOG4PAS47N-lettuce-signed-fastboot-5d674b9b61.zip) and flash it to your device.

---

To get *CyanogenMod* : You can go to Official [CyanogenMod support page for Yuphoria](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=lettuce). Or Download directly [CyanogenMod 12.1](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/135329/cm-12.1-20151119-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1M9-lettuce.zip) and flash it to your device.

Answer (score 0):

You can install stock android YUOS which is available on [Yu official](http://download.yuplaygod.com) website or install [CM website](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=lettuce). I am currently having CM 13.0 snapshot release on my yuphoria and very happy using it. CM community did a wonderful job on fixing bugs and adding improvements to 13.0 release.

Install instructions are provided on respective sites and xda forums.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well, Android and Cyanogen aren't two separate OS internally but Cyanogen is the customized form of Android (with extra privileges). And, I would recommend you to stay with the stock Android if you've recently bought the device.

If you want to put Cyanogen you'll have to go through a lot of steps [Flashing another ROM] (it might make your device unusable/ cause errors after installing Cyanogen). Tell your friends to peace out and keep calm. I prefer the stock Android rather than CyanogenMod.

And, at last if you've money to get another smartphone, you can go ahead and experiment by installing Cyanogen. (:-D)

Comment: Are you certain that you're not mixing things up? Cyanogen is the name used by Steve Kondik who first developed the now community based ROM CyanogenMod (CM) and owns the company Cyanogen Inc. which works with some OEMs to ship devices with custom tailored version of CM, termed as Cyanogen OS. And [Yu Yuphoria comes with Cyanogen OS](http://www.yuplaygod.com/product/yuphoria-cyanogen-os).

Comment: I just explained him in simple launguage. He might be thinking about CM as Windows and Android, like two complete different OS. And, the name has been legally registered that's why they can say it as Cyanogen OS (because Android is Open Sourced). What did I say wrong in layman language? If you say a person who has not even heard of OEM, Flashing etc then should you explain that way?

Comment: Don't always make things complex.. What I said I see - "Cyanogen is the customized form of Android (with extra privileges),
and suggested him to not try flashing up a different ROM (If a guy has bought a new device why should anyone suggest him to experiment if he doesn't know about flashing) and stay with the current Android version. What did I miss?

Comment: Hey guys cool down I know Cyanogen is a based on android and my phone didn't came with the cyanogen because I choose the android yuphoria from amazon. They've got both but I thought I found it a mistake but as you are saying that stock rom is better than okay. And hey I know how to flash.

Comment: Yup, I'm cool. But, it's not right to assume that a person asking a question always knows the pre-requisites. I'm just irritated at him lowering my reputation without any valid reason. If you're a big shot that doesn't mean you can just put -1 on any one -_-

Comment: My mistake: I didn't notice that Yuphoria comes with stock Android as well. Apologies for the confusion caused, but the rest of my earlier comment holds true. Anyhow, I can't argue over other things since it would add to noise here and please don't take voting personally. It implies the opinion of a voter for your post. Please see  [Why is voting important?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [When should I vote down?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)